# How to get windows search history?

Tags: c++, windows

Hi is there any way to get windows search history in some form? I mean programatically in some kind of structure.

Thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows keeps a search history.  Do you mean Internet Explorer history?

Answer (score 0):

Google gave the following registry keys for Windows XP Search Assistant:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5001 (Internet Search Assitant)
>
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5603 (All files and folders)
>
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5604 (Pictures, music, or video)
>
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Search Assistant\ACMru\5647 (Computers or people)